# Language variable missing after the update

Tags: linux, troubleshooting

It appears that language variable is missing after our recent update to our Linux servers.  We are running Redhat 5 on them.  Is there anyway update can remove variables?  The env output shows nothing set for the language although root was not affected by this.

Comment: You are referring to the LANG variable? Perhaps it was defined in /etc/profile and it is not anymore, and maybe the root user has it's own profile or rc file.

Answer (score 2):

An update to the packages on your system could've led to having a file under `/etc/profile.d` being upgraded/replaced, which would be causing the variable `$LANG` to now be gone.

I'd start by taking a look for any `.rpmsave` files which RPM will typically create when it needs to replace a file as part of an update. These would show up in your `/etc` directory or a sub-directory underneath it.

If you find any you can use `diff` to compare the files and manually merge any changes into the new file.